# getting 2 fiferent results for 403 404 pages

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to make custom 404, 403 error pages.

```
ErrorDocument 403 /404.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /404.php
```

this is what I included in .haccess file.

now when I load a 403 error I only get the php part of my 404.php page, and when I load a 404 error I get the full page.

also the php part is formatted differently on one error page then on the other. I think ill go nuts on this one please someone tell me what's going on.

Comment: You always load the 404.php error site on all errors? "ErrorDocument 403 /404.php"

Comment: yes, I do and I get 2 different results.